# Modificar CSS dentro de un componente Angular

Tags: angular, primeng

Tengo que hacer una modificación CSS dentro de un componente para una sola página. Es solo ponerle un `display:none` para que desaparezca.

He intentado llamarlo por su clase y por su clase y la que añade Angular pero no me hace caso.

**¿Es posible modificarlo de alguna manera o es imposible?**

Os dejo lo que tengo actualmente.

Gracias de antemano

HTML

```
<app-header></app-header>
```

HTML del componente en el navegador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El CSS que me gustaría modificar corresponde a esta etiqueta

```
<div _ngcontent-gid-c25="" class="layout-topbar-right">
```

Comment: Puede ser que sea problema de especificidad https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/what-is-css-specificity--cms-34141

Comment: Para hacer que un elemento desaparezca de la página en un componente Angular puedes usar la directiva `ngIf`.

Comment: No, @Lobos, he probado a nombrar las clases del elemento, con selectores... De todas las formas CSS y no me hace caso. Incluso he probado a modificar otro elemento más accesible y nada. Solo me deja si le aplico una clase a app-header

Comment: Rederer2 de Angular está creado con el fin de modificar el DOM, utilízalo. realiza una inyección de este servicio a tu componente y en `AfterViewInit` puedes buscar el div concreto por clase con el método `selectRootElement`.

La manera que @Isaac menciona se suele preferir, porque esto provoca que todo el Subarbol DOM dentro del `if` no se cree, ni los procesos de estos, mejorando el rendimiento.

Comment: ¿Tendría que ponerlo en el ts del componente `app-header` o dónde invoco? Si es dentro del componente no me vale ya que ese componente se usa en más páginas. Si tenéis algún ejemplo, @Mario / Isaac, os lo agradecería mucho. Soy muy nuevo con Angular y ando perdido

Comment: @JaimeMena por supuesto, tendrías que ponerlo en el ts, lee sobre la [inyección de dependencias](https://medium.com/angular-chile/inyecci%C3%B3n-de-componentes-y-directivas-en-angular-6ae75f64be66) en Angular, todo Angular se posa sobre ella. Si el componente `app-header` ya es utilizado, entonces usa la directiva `ngIf`, no tendrás problemas de compatibilidad, mientras no cambies los prototipos de tus funciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente arreglé el fallo de sobreescritura del CSS del componente de PrimeNG añadiendo al `component.ts` lo siguiente (ViewEncapsulation):

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit, **ViewEncapsulation**} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-myapp',
  templateUrl: './myapp.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./myapp.component.scss'],
  **encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,**
})
```

Con esto se puede sobreescribir cualquier estilo CSS del componente hijo desde el padre. Espero que a alguien más le sirva.

¡Gracias a todos!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la directiva `ngIf`.

Si es un componente que usas una sola vez en tu aplicación y quieres que ese elemento desaparezca dinámicamente en función de una condición que se produce en el mismo componente:

```
<div *ngIf="miCondicion">
```

Si es un componente que usas varias veces en tu aplicación y en una de las instancias quieres que ese panel no se muestre, puedes usar la directiva `ngIf` combinada con un atributo `input` en tu componente. Es decir:

El el controller de tu componente:

```
Input() ocultar = false;
```

En el HTML de tu componente:

```
<div *ngIf="ocultar">
```

En el HTML donde quieres usar tu componente y que se oculte ese panel:

```
<mi-componente [ocultar]="true"></mi-componente>
```